# How can we upload images into firebase storage if there is no network connection in android

Tags: android, firebase, storage, image-upload

I am doing the offline update to the `firebase` database.Using the below line. Is there any way to upload the images into storage in offline.

```
firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload anything at all to Storage when the device is offline.  I'm not sure what you're expecting to be able to do without network connectivity.

Also, you should note that the persistence setting for Firebase Realtime Database has no effect on what happens to transfers with Firebase Storage.  They're completely different systems.  Storage simply requires network connectivity, and there's no avoiding that.